# VSCode no longer formats on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

About every couple months, VSCode "formats on save" stops working.

This is mostly for Javascript, React and HTML.

I have prettier installed.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
```

If this the correct way to do it? Is there anything else I can do to future proof this?
It is a little frustrating to have this always break.

Comment: Does format on save work if you disable prettier? If it does, you should file an issue against the prettier extension